# Inherit from class to garantee backward compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, class, rename

Is it good c# style to inherit from a class, to garantee backward compatibility when renaming classes? For examples if classes were used in scripts and the can not be renamed easily over refactoring?

For example:

```
public class NewClass { // Implementation }

[Obsolete("Is obsolete, please use NewClass instead")]
public class OldClass : NewClass { // EMPTY! }
```

Or did i miss some thing here?

Thank you very much

Comment: why dont you update the old class itself?

Comment: What do you mean with `Update`? I just want to rename it, because i like clear and correct code. So the old name in my case is not correct any more. (Some one used to put product names in class names, and renaming the product brokes this logic, which also did not fit to our code convention any more)

Comment: is the name the only thing that changed?

Comment: ive never been in this situation but of course this adds some overhead. so i try to never do this.

Comment: I know that this is not a very good solution, but i could not find any other solution which did not broke anything. I only can imaging that i get trouble when the `NewClass` has some static methods.

Comment: You could implement [`implicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) operators to define conversions between `OldClass` and `NewClass` instead of inheritance. But `as` and `is` operators will not work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think letting a markerclass inherit from old class would be bad usage of inheritance. `NewClass` is not a special Type of `OldClass`. In fact `OldClass` should be removed and only lives on for the sake of compatibility which might be given up at some point in the future. Therefore `NewClass` actually isn't meant to specialize `OldClass`, but replace it.

### Composition and Delegation

```
public class NewClass 
{ 
    // [...]
    public void SomeThing()
    {
        // you move all your stuff to the new class
    }
    // [...]
}

[Obsolete("Is obsolete, please use NewClass instead")]
public class OldClass 
{
    private NewClass newClass = new NewClass();

    // [...]
    public void SomeThing()
    {
        // and delegate your old class calls to that.
        this.newClass.SomeThing();
    }
    // [...]
}
```

### Why

Because otherwise you cannot safely remove it at some point in the future without knowing that nobody did something in the means of

```
NewClass myObject = new OldClass();
```

### Even better: Extract an `interface`

For the Future, think about providing `interface`s for your public API and returning those whereever possible. This makes swapping implementations way easier:

```
public interface ISomeClass
{
    void SomeThing();
}

public class NewClass : ISomeClass
{ 
    // [...]
    public void SomeThing()
    {
        // you move all your stuff to the new class
    }
    // [...]
}

[Obsolete("Is obsolete, please use NewClass instead")]
public class OldClass : ISomeClass
{
    private NewClass newClass = new NewClass();

    // [...]
    public void SomeThing()
    {
        // and delegate your old class calls to that.
        this.newClass.SomeThing();
    }
    // [...]
}
```

This is kind of a mix of your solution and the way I would prefer, since `NewClass` and `OldClass` have to share a common API but do not inherit from each other (they are on the same level of the Inheritance-Hierarchy).

Comment: You are correct. This point is important: `OldClass myObject = new NewClass();` so i will rename the class and fix every bug which will occure. Hope all customer will be happy after the next update. Thank you! :)

Comment: in case you did not notice: i just provided a little edit pointing out the value of interfaces in you usecase.

Comment: Yep, i did notice. I think about it, seems also to be a good solution. Thank you!

Comment: @nozzleman, in OP code, he emptied `OldClass` and moved the code in `NewClass`, and made `OldClass` inherit from `NewClass`. So your example `OldClass myObject = new NewClass();` does not compile, and therefore it's not a problem.

Comment: The perfect solution would be remove completely OldClass. But if you need some backward compatibily, OP solution is quite good. (it actually really depends on how client code requiring compatibiliy use OldClass)

Comment: @GianPaolo you are right, i switched the sides of the assignment (fixed), even now it is possible to assign an instance of `OldClass`to a reference of `NewClass`, which actually is worse and logical nonsense. However, IMO inheritance is not the way to go here (as stated in my answer). But I see your point, feel free to deliver an alternative answer.

Comment: In case of Controls delegation is not an option, so i would stick to inheritance.

Comment: What if you need to cooperate with an assembly that uses old version of the library and contains type checking `if(instance is OldClass) ...` or `var x = instance as OldClass`?

Comment: Then the first approach (Composition and Delegation) should still work. However I would prefer the breaking change even though you would have to apply that chage to depending libs.